# How to get started with Linux kernel development

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm an android developer and I've been doing ROMs for a long time and I wanna get going with kernel development, I understand it's relating to linux kernel itself and got nothing to do with android.

Problem is I can't find any online resources to help me get going.
So what I'm looking for is something a bit official, like the developer site for android,the java tutorials for java, the python tutorials........etc

Is there any thing like that? from linux.org maybe, but I can't find anything on their site.
And what are the things I'm supposed to have a full understanding of? like programming languages (I know it's in C) or anything else?

Keep in mind that I'm only looking to learn driver configuration and compilation.

Comment: https://github.com/jeyaramvrp/kernel-module-programming

Comment: Minimal automated QEMU + Buildroot + BusyBox setup with a few module examples: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Linux Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/), imho, is the best resource for who wants to start in linux kernel development.

Maybe you are interested to buy a book:

- [Linux Kernel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468) 3rd edition 2010;
- [Understanding the linux kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652) 3rd edition 2005;
- [Linux Device Drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005903) 3rd edition 2005.

Free resources (only a few of them):

- [Linux Kernel Hacking](http://bravo.ce.uniroma2.it/kernelhacking2008/);
- [Hacking the Linux 2.6 kernel, Part 1: Getting ready](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-kernelhack1/);
- [Hacking the Linux 2.6 kernel, Part 2: Making your first hack](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-kernelhack2/index.html);
- [Kernel coverage at LWN.net](http://lwn.net/Kernel/);
- [Unreliable Guide To Hacking The Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking.html);
- [The newbie's guide to hacking the Linux kernel](http://tuxradar.com/content/newbies-guide-hacking-linux-kernel);
- [vger.kernel.org - list services for the linux kernel developers](http://vger.kernel.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is following a good book like `Linux Device Drivers 3`, which is freely available as online document on LWN. There are tiny kernel modules skeleton which will help you get started very quickly.